# Parse SDK and Swift: Incorrect argument label in call PFObject 'withoutDataWithObjectId'

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfsubclassing

I subclass PFObject exactly as [described here](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#subclasses-defining/iOS).

Then I create a new instance of the subclassed object without data, but since Swift 1.2 I get an error (It did work perfectly before):

```
var test = Armor(withoutDataWithObjectId: "1234567890")
```

-> Xcode complains:

> "Incorrect argument label in call (have 'withoutDataWithObjectId:',
>   expected: 'className:')"

Why className?  It should get the class name from the class function parseClassName

And I can under no circumstances create a new object with objectId but no data (which I MUST have to fetch it from the local datastore)

This is super annoying as my app doesn't compile any longer.

Comment: What is the definition of the Armor class? You just updated swift version? What version of the Parse SDK are you using?

Comment: v 1.7.2 Parse SDK

Definition exactly like https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#subclasses-defining/iOS

Answer (score 0):

Update to the newest Parse SDK, available [here](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX).

The issue is caused due to necessary adaptions in the Parse SDK after the Swift language update. This issue also occurs with the most recent update to Swift 2.2. The newest (as of today) Parse SDK release 1.13.0 already fixes this.

**UPDATE**

Parse iOS SDK 1.13.0 has a typo and the function `PFUser(withoutDataWithObjectId:)` is called `PFUser(outDataWithObjectId:)`. So upgrading the Parse SDK alone does solve this. Until this is fixed a temporary workaround would be to extend `PFObject` with a convenience initializer. To do this add a new Swift file to your project and insert this:

```
import Parse

extension PFObject {
    convenience init(withoutDataWithObjectId objectId: String?) {
        self.init(outDataWithObjectId: objectId)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It may be a little late to answer this question.

I use swift 1.2, and v 1.7.5 Parse SDK, and it works totally fine.

however, make sure you have define objective-c bridging header in "build setting".

and try to run it, even though there may reports some error

Comment: This has nothing to do with build settings. And i think trying to run code with errors without further analyzing them is not good practice.